# where to put tinyMCE.init

Tags: joomla, tinymce

I use Joomla with K2 and with tinyMCE as the editor. I searched for a plugin to enhance file upload and found a few, but for every one of them I was unable to proceed, because I do not know where to put the tinyMCE.init() initialization code. People in various forums asked that same question and I have not found a clear answer anywhere - either no answer at all or just ambiguous suggestions. Please advise.

**Solved:** as it turns out, the initialization code can be put anywhere where a page is loaded, so either in a HTML file or in an included JavaScript file. For some reason, this information is not given on any of the sites that offer tinyMCE plugins.

Comment: Instead of adding "Solved" to your question title, you should answer your own question with the correct solution, and then accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should put them with the other plugins

/media/editors/tinymce/plugins

and then in the administrator area go to the plugins manager and open up editors - tinymce, click on the advanced tab and then add it to the custom plugins area.

You can also change the functionality to extended to add a few more useful buttons.